# batch script to loop through multiple folders from 1 directory to another

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have no experience in writing batch scripts, but I feel this is an opportunity to give this a shot. Essentially, I have folders with the same weekending dates in two directories. I want to write a script that loops through all the folders in the first directory and move files from each folder to the same folder in another directory.

E.g.

\10.25.2.100\f$\Download\A -- first directory

Folders named:

201310
201311
201312
201313

\10.25.2.100\d$\Download\B -- second directory

Folders named:

201310
201311
201312
201313

In 201310 for the first directory, I want to move 2 files in there to the second directory of 201310.

I am thinking of modifying this script but I have no experience what the syntax means:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET source= \\10.25.2.100\f$\Download\A
SET destroot=\\10.25.2.100\d$\Download\B
SET cdtl=0
:loploop
SET /a cdtl+=1
FOR /f "tokens=%cdtl%*delims=\" %%i IN ("%source%") DO IF NOT "%%j"=="" GOTO loploop
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (
    ' dir /b/s/ad "%source%\converted" '
    ) DO CALL :movedest "%%~dpni%"
)
GOTO :eof

:movedest
SET destdir=%~1
FOR /f "tokens=%cdtl%*delims=\" %%d IN (%1) DO SET destdir=%destroot%\%%e
ECHO MD "%destdir%" 2>NUL
ECHO MOVE /y "%~1\*.*" "%destdir%\"
GOTO :eof
```

I see this as a huge loop, where it's looping through all the folders in the first directory and checking for those 2 files, then comparing the weekending dates of the  folders in the second directory. If they match, put the two files in there.

Comment: Unless you're doing this for fun, you might want to check out [Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy)

Answer (score 0):

See how this goes: it will echo the move commands to the screen, check them and remove the `echo` to make the batch file functional.

```
@echo off
pushd "\\10.25.2.100\f$\"
for /d %%a in (download\A\*) do echo move "%%a\*.*" "download\B\%%~nxa\"
popd
```

Comment: you have a little type o with pod instead of Popd.

Comment: @MattWilliamson  Fixed, ta!